# Getting "declares multiple JSON fields named" error when serializing with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gson

```
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String , MovieDb>>() {}.getType();
gson.fromJson(json, type); //ERROR HERE !!!
```

When I convert from Json to the hashmap object it works fine without minifying enabled. But when minify is enabled it gives me the following error at this line:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class a.a.a.a.b declares multiple JSON fields named a
        at com.google.b.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
        at com.google.b.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.b.e.a(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.b.b.a.b.a(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
        at com.google.b.e.a(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.b.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.b.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.b.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.b.e.a(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.b.b.a.g.a(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:126)
        at com.google.b.e.a(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.b.e.a(Gson.java:926)
        at com.google.b.e.a(Gson.java:892)
        at com.google.b.e.a(Gson.java:841)
        at com.techy.nateshmbhat.moviego.i.onPreExecute(MovieInterface.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:648)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:595)
        at com.techy.nateshmbhat.moviego.i.b(MovieInterface.java:101)
        at com.techy.nateshmbhat.moviego.a.a(Activity_InTheaterMovies.java:55)
```

Comment: send your MovieDb.java code or MovieInterface.java

Comment: Does `MovieDb` extednd another class?

Comment: I had the same problem and it was because the class that was throwing the exception extended another class with an attribute with the same name. Don't know if that's your problem, but if your class extends another, check it.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is most propably because you minify two fields to a same name `a`. Something like:

```
@SerializedName("a")
Long veryLongFieldName;

@SerializedName("a")
Long anotherVeryLongFieldName;
```

Note that these can be either in the same class or if using inheritance it is enough that they are in the same inheritance tree. `Gson` can not assign two values to one minimized field name `a`.

It could of course also be that you have minimized some field to a name that is already reserved by some other unminimized field.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue when I had context property/variable in the model class